# jquery step and send var data in php page

Tags: jquery, forms, post, send

I use the jquery script step form
http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

The form is divided into fourstep and the final step I finish a button that opens a alert window but I would like to send the variable post or get to a php page

I replaced it

```js
onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)   
                {
                    alert("Submitted!"); 
                }
```

I replaced the alert by window.location

```js
onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)  
                    {
                        window.location.href = "test_insert.php";  
                    }
```

but  do not transmit any data to my php page

thank for your help

Comment: This is because you are simply redirecting user to page "test_insert.php" and not posting any data on this page..

Comment: thank goodface87 and Vishal.
 how I transmit variables ?  i have input like `<input type="text"  id="data1" name="data1"   /><input type="text"  id="data2" name="data2"   />`  and i know I should do this  `code`$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: **"name=John&location=Boston"**,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });`
what should I put in the place of **"name=John&location=Boston"**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use jQuery's [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function instead of trying to navigate the whole window to your php page.

```
onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)  
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test_insert.php",
    data: { yourParameterName: yourVariable }
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
}
```

In the data part, you would just have to send whatever your php expects.

Comment: thank for you answer , i found this solution in the doc of ..Form Wizard using jQuery Steps... `onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
{
    var form = $(this);

    form.submit();
}` the form data ar sent to my php page.